# Find Jenkin jobs running more than 24 hours

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I would like to find the Jenkin jobs in the master and client running more than 5 hours and kill it.

I tried multiple options using Thread.getAllStackTraces() and list all the jobs it was not helpful. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: which job types do you use (freestyle, pipeline …)?

Comment: irrespective of job type I would like to clear the build queue in jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching in all the builds (past and present) can take a very long time. As an alternative, I suggest to search only the builds that are currently running, by looking at the activity on the nodes. This is much faster. This piece of pipeline script will list the jobs that have been running for more than 24 hours and send an email if it found one or more.

```
    int stuckJobs = 0

    def busyExecutors = Jenkins.instance.computers.collect { it.executors.findAll { it.isBusy() } }.flatten()

    busyExecutors.each {
        if (it.getElapsedTime() > 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ) {
            println("Job " + it.getCurrentWorkUnit().work.getDisplayName() + " has been running on " + it.getOwner().nodeName + " for " + it.getTimestampString())
            stuckJobs = stuckJobs + 1
        }
    }
    if (stuckJobs > 0) {
        emailext( from:    xxx,
                  subject: "[Jenkins] Stuck jobs report",
                  to:      yyy,
                  body:    "Found ${stuckJobs} job(s) lasting more than 24 hours. Check here: ${BUILD_URL}/console" )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [timeout](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#timeout-enforce-time-limit)

```
pipeline {
    options {
          timeout(time: 5, unit: 'HOURS')
    }
    stages {
          steps {
                sh '...'
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will only have an orbit of the Job. I would like to see the entire Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Get all Jenkins jobs and their builds. Go through the list and check if there are builds running. If you find a build that is running, you can retrieve its time/timestamp/duration. Based on that time you could determine does that build is already running longer than X hours.

```
jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(AbstractItem.class). each {
  println "Job: " + it.fullName + " - " + it.class + " is running: " + it.isBuilding()
  if(it.isBuilding()) {
    def builds = it.getBuilds().each {
      if(it.isBuilding()) { 
        println it.getTime()   //getTimestamp(), getTimeInMillis(), getDuration() ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[WorkflowJob Docu](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-job/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/job/WorkflowJob.html)
[WorkflowRun Docu](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-job/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/job/WorkflowRun.html)
[Jenkins Core API](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/index-core.html)